# Не получается настроить git на VPS

Tags: git

Существует ВПС, на котором много сайтов. У всех функционал один и тот же. Используют одну БД. Только разный вид.
Решил для этой задачи использовать гит. До этого нормально без него обходился.

Есть сайт test.ru и admin.ru

Приступил к созданию гит по мануалам.

В папке admin.ru пишу команду

```
 git init
```

В папке test.ru пишу команду

```
git init
git remote add origin /var/www/пользователь/data/www/admin.ru/
#создаю файл, и меняю его
git commit -a -m "New commit"
#git status - показывает что файл есть
git push origin master
```

и тут вылазит много ошибок, которые я не знаю как исправить.

```
Counting objects: 6, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 417 bytes, done.
Total 6 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (6/6), done.
remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository
remote: error: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent
remote: error: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match
remote: error: the work tree to HEAD.
remote: error:
remote: error: You can set 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to
remote: error: 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into
remote: error: its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless you
remote: error: arranged to update its work tree to match what you pushed in some
remote: error: other way.
remote: error:
remote: error: To squelch this message and still keep the default behaviour, set
remote: error: 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'.
To /var/www/пользователь/data/www/test.ru/admin
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)
error: failed to push some refs to '/var/www/пользователь/data/www/test.ru/
```

Если имеет значение ОС, то CentOS 6

Comment: Проверь права на каталог, попробуй через sudo

Comment: нет, повторил всё сначала. удалил на корню старые папки. создал новые с нужными правами. всё равно такая же ошибка

Answer (score 1):

Git - система контроля версий, а не средство для построения и развертывания кода.

Нельзя пушить в ветку репозитория, соответствующую текущей рабочей копии этого репозитория, т.к. это приведет к нежелательным изменениям и конфликтам в рабочей копии, разрешить которые самостоятельно git никак не сможет - именно об этом говорит эта ошибка.

Да, вы можете установить в конфиге репозитория `receive.denyCurrentBranch = ignore`, заставив git игнорировать данную ошибку. Да, вы можете делать push в другую ветку(скажем `production`), и навесить `post-receive`-хук, делающий merge из этой ветки.

Но и то, и другое делать крайне некорректно - со стороны надежности, безопасности, и просто удобства. Гораздо правильнее использовать для этого средства для развертывания, вызываемые в хуках общего репозитория, либо вообще отдельно.

Comment: Подскажите тогда пожалуйста, какую утилиту лучше мне использовать для моей задачи?